# bson.timestamp.Timestamp - What is the incrementing counter?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

[bson.timestamp.Timestamp](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/timestamp.html) takes two arguments: time and inc.

time is obviously the time value stored in the Timestamp.

What is inc? It is described as the incrementing counter, but what purpose does it serve? What value should it be? Does setting it to 0, 1, or anything else effect the time value stored? Does it change as time passes? Is this not what you want when storing a Date/Timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is inc? It is described as the incrementing counter, but what purpose does it serve?

[BSON type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types) Timestamp value consists of a 64 bit value:

- The first 32 bits are a `time_t` value (seconds since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))
- The second 32 bits are an incrementing `ordinal` for operations within a given second.

To put it simply, it serves a purpose of ordering operations that happens in a given second. i.e. specifying increment by 1, if there are two operations within a second the operations would be `operation1`, `operation2`.

> Is this not what you want when storing a Date/Timestamp?

This is a broad question without knowing the your application use case and context. However, the BSON timestamp type is for **internal** MongoDB use. For most cases, in application development, you will want to use the [BSON date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) type.

PyMongo uses [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) objects for representing dates and times in MongoDB documents.

Lastly, worth noting that BSON timestamp is not to be confused with Python timestamp from [time.time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time).